# API KEY still visible in the https query after using dotenv method for Django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to hide the api key in https query... I end up with the method hiding it with .env file. I did all steps, but the key is still visible. In the query I see the actual numbers, not just variable being processed. What I didn't do or what I did wrong? I set up the dotenv program and did this in the code

In .env file:

```
PROJECT_KEY="1234567890"
```

In settings:

```
PROJECT_KEY_API_KEY = os.environ.get('PROJECT_KEY')
```

In view:

```
  from django.conf import settings

api_key = PROJECT_KEY_API_KEY
```

In the actual query line in https address it tells me: ...&api_key=1234567890

I would like this key will be processed to external host, but not visible in the address.

Thank you!

update:
Kind of managed to do what I was aiming for, but it made it worst...
view:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests
load_dotenv()
```

in view function:

```
api_key=os.getenv('PROJECT_KEY')
...
address=requests.get(f"https://baseaddress/?code={api_key}")
...
```

But now I'm getting mistake from the server(type error)
And my whole second part of line invisible and looks like this:
https://baseaddress/?<Response%20[200]>

So, external site doesn't recognize parameters because they are behind this Response :(...
So I'm kind of confused what to do next... How to achieve security of a key, if it has to be in the html request...

Comment: Now I understand that I have to set  up the React for this purpose and whole React server? Would proxying the api key be better solution? I have Django environment running on my machine and I don't understand what complexities adding react server would lead to... I would like to end up with the simplest solution for just first step and don't complicate server/environment part of the program further for at least right now. Any advise about these concerns?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely solve this task, but I came to some intermediate conclusion. If somebody have some better solution please share, it might help to other fellows. My decision was to ask external site to accept queries only from my domain, so if api_key is stolen, it doesn't really matter. Also it seems Rest and React have some ways to deal with it, but I have to study them to come to conclusion.

Comment: Also, just a thought. When you doing internal structure of the site, it's much easier to protect your keys. I might be wrong, but it is have to be easier in comparison to the keys towards external sites, since the key itself must be present in the http or https query, even briefly if you using proxy. Possible to encrypt the key, but then you have to have the key for encryption which can be caught? So i think it is very difficult to achieve complete security of a key while communicating with external sites. Just thoughts...